# Removing the Superfish Shopping Assistant for Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, spyware

Today I noticed I was getting an AJAX loaded "Shopping Assistant" in my Google Search results:

[image]

This isn't a Google thing from what I can tell, looks like I have some spyware in my Chrome browser. Anybody know how to remove? (not listed in the Extension)

Answer (score 12):

In my case it was `Translate selection 1.2` addon.

Try to open [a console](http://img.iamntz.com/jing/2013-09-01-07@07h25_59.png) (f12 or ctrl+shift+i) into a simple page (that is not chrome store or start page) and start disabling extensions one by one then refresh the page.

[This is how it looks like](http://img.iamntz.com/jing/2013-09-01-07@07h27_48.png) when the thing is still on.

Comment: I removed this since the option to disable ads is disabled!!!

Answer (score 3):

This is a spyware that comes with Flash Video Downloader extension in chrome. UnInstall Flash Video downloader that should get rid of this.

Comment: In my case it was the Hola extension.

Comment: In my case, the "New Tab Page" extension.

Comment: If you remove the extension it will not help in all cases. The extension hides itself and will be loaded every time you look at a webpage (check with firebug or debugger). In your Chrome extensions directory you need to search for either sj.js or script-superfish.js and remove the related extension (the complete directory) manualy.

Answer (score 1):

I found the same malware in `Translate Selection 1.3 extension`. It seems that Chrome Web Store is full of complaints about the problem: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/translate-selection/goanabmlmgfinmjohhepcpffcnkeobjm/reviews.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Superfish WindowShopper extension installed, perform following steps:

1. Click the Chrome menu on the browser toolbar, select Tools and then click on Extensions.
2. In the Extensions tab, remove (by clicking on the Recycle Bin) the Superfish WindowShopper extension.
3. The BetterChrome extension also contains this. Uncheck "Enable SuperFish Suggestions" in the BeterChrome options.